# Basis for proper rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Suppose $F$ is a field, and let $F(x)$ denote the $F$-vector space of all rational functions $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $f,g\in F[x]$ are polynomials, with $g$ different from zero. Let $F(x)_p$ denote the subspace of F(x) of all proper fractions, i.e. all $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where degree($f$) $<$ degree($g$). Show that:

> (a) $F(x)$ is isomorphic to $F[x]\oplus F(x)_p $ as an $F$-vector space.
>
> (b) If $\mathcal{I}=\{p(x)\in F[x] \mid p \text { is a monic irreducible polynomial}\}$, then
>
> $$\beta= \{\frac{x^{j}}{p(x)^{k}} \mid p(x)\in \mathcal{I}, 0\leq j< \text{degree}(p); k\geq 1 \}  $$ is a basis for $F(x)_p$ as an $F$-vector space.

I am done with part (a), but I don't know how to proceed in part (b).
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you not write ${f(x) \over g(x)} = \sum_k f_k {x^k \over g(x) }$? (Assuming that $g$ is monic.)

Comment: Hint: Use polynomial division.  Given $f,g \in F[x]$, you can write $f(x) = q(x) g(x) + r(x)$ with $\deg(r) < \deg(g)$ or $r(x) = 0$.  What does that tell you about $f(x)/g(x)$?

Comment: @SpamIAm That's what I did in item a. My problem is with b.

Answer (score 4):

This is partial fractions.

$M=F(x)/F[x]$ is a torsion $F[x]$-module. Since $F[x]$ is a PID, $M$ is the direct sum of its $p(x)$-primary components, for irreducible polynomials $p(x) \in F[x]$. Show that any element in $F(x)/F[x]$ which is annihilated by a power of $p$ by can be represented in the form $r(x)/p(x)^n$, and use this to show that the elements you have written down form a basis of the $p(x)$-primary component of $F(x)/F[x]$.

Comment: Is $F(x)/F[x]$ a quotient or do you just mean to consider $F(x)$ as an $F[x]$ module? Could you generally add a bit more detail to your answer? I'm trying to understand but finding it difficult.

Comment: @Mingus The quotient $F(x)/F[x]$ is a $F[x]$-module as you can define a product $F[x]\times F(x)/F[x]\to F(x)/F[x]$ which behaves very well. Further it is a torsion module, i.e., for every $u=\overline{\frac{a}{b}}\in F(x)/F[x]$ there exist an element  $r\in F[x]$ with $ru=0$ (which means $ru\in F[x]$), can you find such $r$? With all this in mind, just use the fact that any torsion module over a PID can be written as the direct sum of its $p-primary$ components. Details of the last part here https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/tag/p-primary-component/